# Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer Button View Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

I noticed, or do not see, that there is no View Designers button in the tool strip in Solution Explorer.  VS2010 had both a View Code and View Designer, but with VS2012 I see only View Code.

Is it possible to get the View Designer back?  If so, how?

Comment: I want to know this too. Actuall the more irritating one for me is the missing "View Code" button. It's irritating as hell trying to edit code on a form or custom control...

Comment: When I said icon, I meant the button. I will correct my text. Yes, it is quite annoying to have to right click or remember F7 or Shift-F7 and that changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760938/where-has-design-view-gone-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: That is not a solution for several reasons. One, the interface, take ASP.Net, is different than on WPF. There is the lack of a button series, my original point, of code/designer/markup with the markup being on ASP.Net. Traveling to the bottom left corner is no different than going to the market in New York to by a bottle of milk, when you live in Los Angeles. I could go on, but Microsoft lacks the convenient buttons in the toolbar. I did not look at VS2013 yet, but hopefully it came (will come back) back.