# Where has Design View gone in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio and I am writing a C# program. However I can't see ho to switch to design view. In Visual Studio 2010 I seem to recall that there were tabs beside the main text area that let you select between code, design or split views?

By the way when I was installing VS2012 I select C++ as my 'main language' so I don't know if that might have something to do with the missing design view?

Comment: Have you tried going to View --> Designer ? on your Menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

When you are open a xaml file you can see Design tab on the left bottom of the VS.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click select at your file to view than find  view design bottom or  can see Design tab on the left bottom as first answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the .xaml.cs file selected then go to view->designer.